# C# project in Visual Studio Code is missing the Accord.targets 3.8.0 package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget, accord.net

I'm trying to build an open source Git project locally on my computer using Visual Studio Code. The project I'm trying to build is [MusicAnalyser](https://github.com/Seank23/MusicAnalyser). I've successfully set up Visual Studio Code, installed Git, installed C# (I think; I have quite a bit of experience as a Java programmer, but I am new to C#) and cloned the repository. Admittedly, I am not a Git expert, but I don't think that matters here. I now want to build the project, but I get the following error:

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see *[Troubleshooting package restore errors](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105)*. The missing file is *..\packages\Accord.3.8.0\build\Accord.targets*.

I've therefore installed the NuGet Package Manager GUI and started looking for *Accord.targets*. I can't find it... I've tried installing a whole bunch of Accord packages, hoping the one I need happened to be in one of them, but no luck. I'm stuck!

I can't find Accord.targets anywhere online either, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something far more basic. For example, I'm trying to figure out where NuGet installs packages, but I can't find them anywhere on my local computer. Also, I've tried to use the option to 'Restore NuGet Packages', but I'm out of my depth. I don't know how to run that or where to get started.

I admit there are too many new things for me so I don't know what to do next. Of course I have googled a lot before posting this question, however did not find anything helpful. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The project dependencies are listed in the `packages.config` file (https://github.com/Seank23/MusicAnalyser/blob/master/MusicAnalyser/packages.config). You just need to restore them. Assuming you have the .NET extension installed, you should be able to hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and select *.NET Restore Project*. Actually, if you have the extension installed, Visual Studio Code will usually ask if you want to restore when you open the project.

If it comes down to it, you can also open the terminal, navigate to the project folder and enter:

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: Thanks, padeso, for the quick response! I actually tried that before as well, but when I run 'dotnet restore' in a Terminal in the project root directory (where MusicAnalyser.sln is), or in what I believe the actual project dir is (the folder containing MusicAnalyser.csproj) I get this response:

'Determining projects to restore...
Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.'

I tried your other suggestion as well, hitting F1 and selecting '.NET Restore Project' but nothing happens, I assume for the same reason 'dotnet restore' cannot do it either...

Comment: Try in the MusicAnalyser folder, where MusicAnalyser.csproj and packages.config are.

Comment: I did, result is the same. I've added the Accord, Accord.Audio and Accord.Math packages to the project (as per packages.config) and when I attempt a restore in the dir with MusicAnalyser.csproj and packages.config, a restore command now actually does something. However, the Omnisharp server still comes back with the same result: `This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Accord.3.8.0\build\Accord.targets.`

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I cloned the repository and had the same problem in VSCode. I tried VS2022, which was able to restore the dependencies, but it still wouldn't build it due to a different missing dependency, `XanderUI`. This may be one of those projects that can only be built on the original developer's system.

Comment: Many thanks, @padeso, kudos for trying! I think it may not be worth the effort, but it was fun to learn, as I'm a programmer who also loves music and this project really looks like it can bring me something.